# Getting error while plotting the dendrogram for the spearmanr correlation

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scipy, data-science

I am getting an error while plotting the **dendrogram** for the **spearmanr** correlation.
Below is the code I am using

```
corr = np.round(scipy.stats.spearmanr(full_data[list_of_continous]).correlation, 4)
corr_condensed = hc.distance.squareform(1-corr)
z = hc.linkage(corr_condensed, method='average')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
dendrogram = hc.dendrogram(z, labels=full_data[list_of_continous].columns, orientation='left', leaf_font_size=30)
plt.show()
```

Below is the error I am getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-9873c0be8dc7> in <module>()
      1 corr = np.round(scipy.stats.spearmanr(full_data[list_of_continous]).correlation, 4)
----> 2 corr_condensed = hc.distance.squareform(1-corr)
      3 z = hc.linkage(corr_condensed, method='average')
      4 fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
      5 dendrogram = hc.dendrogram(z, labels=full_data[list_of_continous].columns, orientation='left', leaf_font_size=30)

/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.py in squareform(X, force, checks)
   1844             raise ValueError('The matrix argument must be square.')
   1845         if checks:
-> 1846             is_valid_dm(X, throw=True, name='X')
   1847 
   1848         # One-side of the dimensions is set here.

/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.py in is_valid_dm(D, tol, throw, name, warning)
   1920                 if name:
   1921                     raise ValueError(('Distance matrix \'%s\' must be '
-> 1922                                      'symmetric.') % name)
   1923                 else:
   1924                     raise ValueError('Distance matrix must be symmetric.')

ValueError: Distance matrix 'X' must be symmetric.
```

Comment: What is `corr.shape`?

Comment: the shape is (94,94)

Answer (score 3):

Variable `corr` might have nan values which might deform it.
Try:

```
corr = np.nan_to_num(corr)
```

Update:

skipping

```
    corr_condensed = hc.distance.squareform(1-corr)
```

works without any error for me.

So

```
corr = np.round(scipy.stats.spearmanr(full_data[list_of_continous]).correlation, 4)
z = hc.linkage(corr, method='average')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
dendrogram = hc.dendrogram(z, labels=full_data[list_of_continous].columns, orientation='left', leaf_font_size=30)
plt.show()
```

should work for you too.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure the matrix is symmetric, set checks=False

`corr_condensed = hc.distance.squareform(1-corr, checks=False)`

Comment: Sometimes we need this option in practice, although it might sound weird because the matrix is (almost) symmetric but the error says it must be symmetric. As we already know, numbers in the programming world such as floating points are not perfect like we imagine theoretically.